# Do wired ethernet cameras exist?

Tags: webcam, camera, ip-camera, network-camera

Do wired ethernet (i.e. rj45) cameras exist.  Cameras which have a single rj45 cable which connect into a network card, from which they can be used to record/view video?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are plenty of camera's with an ethernet connection out there.
They are very common for CCTV purposes.
They can send the video as a TCP network stream and usually have a web-based configuration/control interface on-board.
Some also allow motion-jpeg caputuring or individual images as jpeg images.
There is also a standarized software API (called ONVIF) that is supported by almost all camera's in the mid to end high ranges.

Biggest brandnames in the business are Axis, Bosch, Panasonic and Sony.

PS. Such camera's are not really designed for a point to point connection with a PC, but it will work.
Typical setup are multiple camera's connected by a normal computer network. Somewhere in the network is a control computer with a big harddisk. From here the camera's are controlled (zoom, pan, tilt) and the video-streams are stored. It's also possible that the control PC and the storage are separate (a NAS is often used for storage).

Disclaimer: I'm not directly involved myself, but I happen to work as an IT guy on a Bosch site where they develop such camera's.

Comment: Do you have a link?  I can't seem to find any cameras which have a single simple rj45 cable/connector only?

Comment: @oshirowanen Googling "ethernet camera", brings up plenty of results, and he also gave you several manufactures to check out -- Axis alone has plenty of different models you can pick from.

Comment: I can see plenty of ethernet cameras on google, but non of them seem to have a a single rj45 connection and ethernet cable.  They are either wireless, or have a bnc connection.

Comment: @oshirowanen It seems like you're a little allergic to looking up info on your own. :)  Did you check with the manufacturers?  Try looking at some of the _many_ PoE (power over Ethernet) cameras.  For example (first one I looked at on Axis' page): "AXIS Q16 Network Camera Series" - "Connectors: RJ-45 10BASE-T/100BASE-TX PoE"

Comment: @techie007 Seems he is only interested in consumer-grade stuff. You won't find many candidates there...